# Plugin to book course and pay online for it

Tags: plugins, paypal

I got a request from a client. He need to manage a school with courses 2-3 day a month. He have to open-close date and manage it easily. Then when a person choose a date, he need to register, and pay with paypal, get a confirmation and email send to the customer and the teacher....

Question, do you know 1 or 2 plugin that can help me get this done in WP ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it will do **exactly** what you want, but it sure can **help** you to start.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/booking/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bookings/

http://www.checkfront.com/extend/wordpress/

and many others that you can find [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=booking%20) or in google